# Using aws cli without a homedirectory

Tags: openshift, aws-cli

I need to use aws cli on an OpenShift Cluster that is quite restricted - it looks like the homedirectory is set to /, while the user in the container does not have permissions to write to /.

The only directory that is writeable from that user is /tmp. Now I need to use aws cli from within a pod of this OpenShift cluster. I came across the environment variables AWS_CONFIG_FILE and AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE. So I would place each a credentials file and a config file to /tmp.

When running `aws configure list-profiles` with this setup, only the one profile from AWS_SHARD_CREDENTIALS_FILE is listed. Not the one from AWS_CONFIG_FILE.
So it looks to me like AWS_CONFIG_FILE is not respected by aws cli.

Do you have an idea why these files might not be respected by the aws executable? Is there a way to pass the location of these files directly to the cli as parameter or s.th.?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of configuring files for the AWS CLI, I would assume you could set the following 2 environment variables: *AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID* and *AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY* and issue your CLI commands immediately.

```
bruno@pop-os ~> export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE"
bruno@pop-os ~> export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY" 
bruno@pop-os ~> aws cloudformation list-stacks --region us-east-2  
{
    "StackSummaries": []
}
```

To answer on:

> So it looks to me like AWS_CONFIG_FILE is not respected by aws cli.

The AWS CLI does respect this.

> You can specify a non-default location for the config file by setting
> the AWS_CONFIG_FILE environment variable to another local path.